# Обработка массива через LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть текстовый файл, где записаны номер машины и время, на  сколько брали в прокат машину.

Как с помощью *linq* написать запрос, который считал бы, на сколько была снята 1, 2, 3, 4 или 5 машина?

Вот пример строк из текстового файла:

```
02,02:29:47
04,01:15:20
01,00:22:13
```

Comment: А почему обязательно через LINQ? А без LINQ у вас получается? Покажите свой код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что Вы считали все строки файла и записали их в string[] который назвали lines.
Для поиска интересующих строк (например 1-ая машина) советую воспользоваться методом-расширением Where:

```
var firstCarEntries = lines.Where(line => line.Split(',').FirstOrDefault() == "01");
```

Для подсчета суммы подойдет метод Sum, в котором Вам необходимо, в Вашем случае, строковое значение конвертировать в TimeSpan:

```
var allCarsTimeSum = lines.Sum(line => TimeSpan.Parse(line.Split(',').LastOrDefault() ?? "00:00:00"));
```

Скомбинировав эти два метода Вы сможете получить искомое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
var result = (
    from line in lines
    let attrs = line.Split(',')
    where attrs.Length == 2
    let carNum = attrs[0]
    let timeUsage = TimeSpan.Parse(attrs[1])
    // Можно добавить необходимую фильтрацию, чтобы выбрать только нужные автомобили
    where new [] {"01", "02"}.Contains(carNum)
    //where carNum == "02"
    select new { carNum, timeUsage } into carUsage
    group carUsage by carUsage.carNum into g
    select new { CarNum = g.Key, TotalTime = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks))}
 );
```

Ну и более полный пример на [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ifzktL).

Comment: Ругается на индекс вне границ массива(

Comment: @Desert Значит не в каждой строке есть номер машины и время через запятую.

Comment: @Desert Я добавил дополнительную проверку - попробуйте теперь.

Comment: Вот посмотрите мой код, я просто аналогичный пример делаю, и   поэтому спросил на таком примере.Просто не пойму из-за чего ругается(

Comment: @Desert Там где Вы пытаетесь получить `время отклонения на узел` - Вы берете в качестве номера второй элемент массива, а в качестве времени пятый элемент массива. Значит, чтобы не было ошибки, Вам нужно гарантировать, что в массиве существует хотя бы 5 элементов. Для этого, после строки `let a = line.Split(',')` Вы можете добавить строку с условием `where a.Length >= 5`

Comment: Да беру 5 и 2 элемент, вставил условие всё равно ругается(

Comment: @Desert Это странно, конечно. А на какой именно строке останавливается отладчик, когда появляется исключение?

Comment: @Desert Ну и если бы Вы смогли выложить куда-нибудь файл с данными, в дополнение к коду, (или его содержимое на тот же http://pastebin.com/) было бы проще понять проблему.

Comment: Сейчас выложу  файл

Comment: Вот http://pastebin.com/7fTHkBsz

Comment: @Desert Я Вам на совсем скорую руку могу предложить такой вариант: http://pastebin.com/TFzY3MF4
Но это все не очень правильно, все равно. По хорошему счету Вам нужно один раз распарсить файл, превратить строки в атрибуты нужного типа и потом работать с ними, чем делать одно и тоже много раз. Если найду время - я постараюсь немного модифицировать Ваш код.

Comment: @Desert Вот немного переработанный код в целом: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xLMoIk Отпишите по результатам.